# Display negative values in canvas line graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I am using html5 canvas element to draw line chart. The chart works fine with positive values. But when provided negative values, the chart is not drawn correctly.

This is what I have tried. Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/nshX6/142/

```
  function getMinY () {

        var min = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                if(data.values[i].Y < min) {
                    min = data.values[i].Y;
                                   }
            }
        return Math.ceil(min);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here are some tool functions you can use to build a flexible graph.

Your flexible graph will be able to show **any range of data** and it will **always fit** on the available canvas size.

**calcSourceMinMax:** Calculates the minimum and maximum value from a data array.

**mapRange:** Takes any data value and maps it into a proportional value that is guaranteed to be inside the minimum and maximum of the graphs displayable width & height. This allows your data array to contain any range of values and still never fall outside the graphing display area.

**getDisplayXY:** Takes a specified x,y data value and finds its display X,Y coordinate on the graph.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var xPadding = 40;
var yPadding = 30;

// Notice I changed The X values
var data = { values:[
  { X: 0, Y: -120 },
  { X: 2, Y: 28 },
  { X: 3, Y: 18 },
  { X: 4, Y: 34 },
  { X: 5, Y: 40 },
  { X: 6, Y: 80 },
  { X: 7, Y: 80 }
]};


// calc the drawable graph boundaries
var graphLeft=xPadding;
var graphRight=canvas.width-xPadding;
var graphTop=yPadding;
var graphBottom=canvas.height-yPadding;

// graph styling
var dotRadius=3;

// calc the min & max values of data.values (calc both X & Y ranges)
var rangeX=calcSourceMinMax(data.values,'X');
var rangeY=calcSourceMinMax(data.values,'Y');

// draw the graph content
var starting=getDisplayXY(data.values[0].X,data.values[0].Y);
dot(starting,dotRadius);
for(var i=1;i<data.values.length;i++){
  var ending=getDisplayXY(data.values[i].X,data.values[i].Y);
  connector(starting,ending);
  dot(ending,dotRadius);
  starting=ending;
}

// draw the graph axes
var y0=getDisplayXY(graphLeft,0).displayY;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(graphLeft,graphTop);
ctx.lineTo(graphLeft,graphBottom);
ctx.moveTo(graphLeft,y0);
ctx.lineTo(graphRight,y0);
ctx.strokeStyle='#D3E';
ctx.stroke();

// draw the graph legends
ctx.textAlign='right';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
var y0=getDisplayXY(graphLeft,0).displayY;
var yMin=getDisplayXY(graphLeft,rangeY.min).displayY;
var yMax=getDisplayXY(graphLeft,rangeY.max).displayY;
var xMax=getDisplayXY(graphRight,rangeX.max).displayX;
ctx.fillText(rangeY.min,graphLeft-10,yMin);
ctx.fillText(0,graphLeft-10,y0);
ctx.fillText(rangeY.max,graphLeft-10,yMax);
ctx.fillText(rangeX.max,graphRight+10,y0);



///////////////////////////////////
// HELPER FUNCTIONS
///////////////////////////////////

// 
function getDisplayXY(valueX,valueY){
  // calc the display X & Y from data.values[i]
  x=mapRange(valueX,rangeX.min,rangeX.max,graphLeft,graphRight);
  // Note: canvas y values increase going downward
  // so swap graphTop & graphBottom
  y=mapRange(valueY,rangeY.min,rangeY.max,graphBottom,graphTop);
  return({displayX:x,displayY:y})
}
//
function connector(starting,ending){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(starting.displayX,starting.displayY);
  ctx.lineTo(ending.displayX,ending.displayY);
  ctx.stroke();
}
//
function dot(position,radius){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(position.displayX,position.displayY);
  ctx.arc(position.displayX,position.displayY,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}


// map source values into a designated range
function mapRange(value, sourceLow, sourceHigh, mappedLow, mappedHigh) {
  return mappedLow + (mappedHigh - mappedLow) * (value - sourceLow) / (sourceHigh - sourceLow);
}
// mapping helper function
function calcSourceMinMax(a,prop){
  var min=1000000;
  var max=-1000000;
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var value=a[i][prop];
    if(value<min){min=value;}
    if(value>max){max=value;}
  }
  return({min:min,max:max});
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
```

You will want to style the graph according to your design needs. This minimal example shows a legend containing the x,y axes and the min,max ranges of values.

Also, the x-axis is put at the y=0 value. You will also want to check that there is indeed a y=0 in the range of your y values. If not, you might move the x-axis at the bottom of your graph.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: It was a complete overwrite. but helped greatly. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifaying this parameters :

```
var xPadding = 30;
var yPadding = 30;
```

To :

```
var xPadding = 30;
var yPadding = 100;
```

After that you need to change Y step to be bigger.

**EDIT**

In case that you have dynamic data you need to normalize values.

**step 1** : find min value for Y

**step 2** : if min value is less than zero (0) you need to normalize all values to be positive. Add that value to every element of array

**step 3** : shift Y axes to it's new position.

Comment: What if the data is dynamic?